# How to add my Compose Multiplatform application to SendTo menu in Windows?

Tags: windows, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform, kotlin-desktop

I have a cross-platform application created using Compose Multiplatform. I need to add it to SendTo menu (this menu is available in Windows Explorer when user right-clicked a file).

I've tried to find any options to implement it using Gradle. But there is no special options in nativeDistributions/windows.

I've also tried to implement it on application launch in `main()` function with the code below:

```
val appPath = Paths.get("C:/Program Files/MyApp/MyApp.exe")
val sendToDir = Paths.get(System.getenv("APPDATA"), "Microsoft", "Windows", "SendTo")
val shortcutPath = sendToDir.resolve("MyApp.lnk")
Files.createLink(shortcutPath, appPath)
```

It doesn't work and throws an exception:

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\MyApp.lnk -> C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:89)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.createLink(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:622)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.createLink(Files.java:1112)
```

How to create shortcut in Windows SendTo directory using Compose Multiplatform?

Answer (score 2):

The Windows folder with sendTo links is not administrator-permission protected:

```
%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo
```

Just create a link there to the application you want to run.

## EDIT 1

Try creating a .lnk file. It has a binary format, so a java lib like **mslinks** should help you accomplishing this task programatically:

https://github.com/DmitriiShamrikov/mslinks

The documentation says **Files.createLink** creates hard links, which can be a problem since *Program Files* is a folder protected with admin privileges.

## EDIT2

Write a .vbs file with these lines and call the shell to run if from your app. It will create the .lnk file using native Windows components (VBScript):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%") & "\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo\MyApp.lnk")
oShellLink.TargetPath = "C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyApp.exe"
oShellLink.Save
```

You can delete the .vbs file after the script is finished.

Comment: But it's thrown AccessDeniedException. I've updated the question text, please check it.

Comment: Files.createLink creates a hard link, which may have problems in some OSs. Try creating a normal windows link manually first to see if it works, or if there is some other problem preventing the folder from being accessed.

Comment: Manually it is creating without problems. Also when I trying to use `createFile` instead of `createLink`, it works without errors and file successfully created. But how to create link programmatically?

Comment: I edited my answer with a java lib that features .lnk read/write. If you end up having problems even after using it, there is still a solution that calls VBScript, but mixing up too many programming languages may sound too odd for such a simple file creation problem. Hope you can manage it with java only!

Comment: As I see it is not possible to include Java library mslinks to Kotlin Multiplatform Project. I've added `implementation(files("./libs/mslinks-1.1.0.jar"))` and it synchronized without problems. But Kotlin doesn't see any classes from this library (for example ShellLinkHelper is unresolved reference),

Comment: Oh, I see. I will update the answer with a vbscript code that creates the link. Your app just have to create the .vbs file and call the shell to run it.